# Is there anyway to hook up Python/Tkinter to an already running Tcl/Tk app?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I work a lot on Pure Data, an app written in Tcl/Tk and C.  I'd like to be able to make a python API for plugins for modifying the Tcl/Tk GUI.  To do this, it seems that I would need to be able to pass the running Tk instance to python, then have Tkinter use that Tcl/Tk instance for its commands.  So something like:

```
root = Tk(pid_of_running_app)
```

Comment: To clarify, I should say the aim is to have Tkinter use an already running Tcl/Tk instance rather than launching its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [send](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1055) command, you can do exactly that (to Tk applications, not plain Tcl applications).  I do this all the time from my Emacs (connect to running Tk applications).

Tcl/Tk won't let you enslave another process, however using the `send` command, you can easily send over any commands you want to.  Just find the "name" of the other interpreter by using [`[winfo interps]`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M18) (note: the name of your Tk application can be gotten/set by [`[tk appname]`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/tk.htm#M5).  At which point, any command you want to have executed in the other interpreter would be sent over by evaluating

```
send $other_app tk_dialog . "Sample Dialog" "See, it's this easy." "" 0 Ok
```

Comment: I know Tcl/Tk's send, but I don't see how to use send to make Tkinter send its commands to a running Tcl/Tk app without completely writing my own infrastructure for it.  Tkinter launches a Tcl/Tk instance, I was hoping to be able to tell Tkinter to instead use an existing, running instance of Tcl/Tk.

Comment: @Hans-Christoph Tkinter isn't written as a portal to other processes, it's written to provide Tk widgets in a python environment.  That said, since `send` just sends over the commands as-is, there's very little you'd have to write on your end, just build up the command strings and `send` them over.

Answer (score 1):

The options are to use Tk's built-in `send` infrastructure (as Trey mentions) or to use the [comm](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/comm.html) package from [Tcllib](http://www.purl.org/tcl/home/software/tcllib/). It should be possible to talk the comm protocol directly from Python, but I've never looked into the details so you might as well lead the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sockets to communicate between the 2 apps.